# Какую логику выбрать для обработки одинаковых действий с текстовыми полями?

Tags: android, kotlin, for

Есть 4 текстовых поля. Каждое из них в процессе потери фокуса проверяется на ряд условий. Хотелось бы путем объединения этих полей в какую-то сущность применить к ней ту или иную функцию (чтобы не повторять один и тот же код 4 раза для каждого поля).

Это может быть массив или, например, when?

массив - список

```
val listDataString = listOf(date1, date2, date3, date4)
listDataString.setOnFocusChangeListener { ... функция_проверки()

for(i in listDataString ).setOnFocusChangeListener { ... функция_проверки()

listDataString.all { setOnFocusChangeListener } ... функция_проверки()
```

условие

```
when (!hasFocus)
date1, date2, date3, date4 -> функция_проверки()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, у вас есть список из `EditText`:

```kotlin
val dates = listOf<EditText>(date1, date2, date3)
```

Чтобы пройтись по всем элементам списка, напишем [цикл](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#for-loops):

```kotlin
for(date in dates) {
    date.setOnFocusChangeListener {
        ...
    }
}
```

То же самое можно сделать с помощью функции [forEach](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) из стандартной библиотеки:

```kotlin
dates.forEach { date ->
    date.setOnFocusChangeListener {
        ...
    }
}
```

Про циклы можно почитать документацию [на русском](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops).

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться. Кстати по ForEach мало информации. А как мне кажется он лучше подходит. Только почему у вас forEach { `date` ->  здесь? Вроде везде в примерах i. Или это без разницы? А i - это не итое-значение, а просто любой символ?

Comment: всё получилось.